# Any body know a method that would iterate over a pyspark dataframe and get all its nested array length and append it to schema?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, nested

```
name    location
India   [{country:India},{city:["mumbai","chennai"]},{country:India},{city:["mumbai","chennai","california"]}]
```

I wanted to get mapping something like this

```
name, location[0].country,location[0].city
name, location[0].country,location[0].city
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("location", F.explode("location")).select(
    "name",
    "location.country",
    "location.city"
).show()
```

Comment: Problem is I cannot hard code the variables. So we did write a custom code that does that

Comment: We did create a custom function in pyspark to fix this .